# Separate full name in C

Tags: c

I want to separate the whole name into only first and last name, but the name can be more than one. I wrote a code like this, but this code is only set to 2 names.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    char* first = strtok(temp[i].full, " ");
    char* second = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char* last = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (last == NULL) {
        strcpy(data[i].name, first);
        strcpy(data[i].surname, second);
    }
    else{
        strcpy(data[i].name, first);
        strcpy(data[i].secName, second);
        strcpy(data[i].surname, last);
    }
}
```

But the format I need is:

```
full name : jack joe woo
name: jack joe
surname: woo
```

or

```
full name : jack joe jes woo
name: jack joe jes
surname: woo
```

How can I get only the last word as a surname and the rest as a name?

Comment: Guess what: surnames can be multiple words, too.  Like "Carl St. Clair" or "Ludwig van Beethoven" ;)

Comment: I need only one last name. @paulsm4

Comment: Probably should be checking for null on all your strtok calls... just in case.  IRL, because space doesn't necessarily mean next part of name, this would be handled by multiple inputs "Enter first name:" - "Enter Last Name".  That way the user handles the parsing.

Comment: But to answer here, you can place your strtok into a loop checking for NULL.  When NULL, you know you have the last thing entered in the previous loop iteration.

Comment: dadaturk, Last name does not always equal surname.  Best to stick with one nomenclature.  Sometime the surname/family name comes first (or the middle)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This block of code is apparently intended only for cultures where last name == surname. There could be some other block that works differently, perhaps under control of a flag.

Comment: @dadaturk: So you're willing to truncate "Carl St. Clair" to "firstname= Carl, surname= Clair"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strrchr()` to search for the last space character. Everything before that is the first name, everything after is the last name.

```
char *lname = strrchr(temp[i].full, ' ');
if (lname) {
    *lname = '\0'; // replace space with null terminator
    lname++; // point to the beginning of last name
    strcpy(data[i].name, temp[i].full);
    strcpy(data[i].surname, lname);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `*lname = 0;`, could use `strncpy()` to allow fullname to be `const`.  Yet good idea to check form end.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Since the original code uses `strtok()`, I assumed it's safe to overwrite `temp[i].full`. The name implies that it's temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which uses `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Note that this function will modify the string,
//because that is the way that strtok behaves.
void print_names( char *full_name )
{
    char *current, *next;

    printf( "full name: %s\n", full_name );

    current = strtok( full_name, " " );

    printf( "first names:" );

    while( (next = strtok( NULL, " " )) != NULL )
    {
        printf( " %s", current );
        current = next;
    }

    printf( "\nlast name: %s\n", current );
}

int main( void )
{
    //Note that the string we pass to the function must
    //be writable, because the function uses strtok.
    char test_string[] = "jack joe jes woo";
    print_names( test_string );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
full name: jack joe jes woo
first names: jack joe jes
last name: woo
```

However, using `strtok` has several disadvantages:

1. It modifies the string that it is working on.
2. It is not thread-safe.

Therefore, I have provided an alternate solution which does not use `strtok`, but uses `strrchr` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_names( const char *full_name )
{
    printf( "full name: %s\n", full_name );

    char *p = strrchr( full_name, ' ' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "parse error\n" );
        return;
    }

    printf( "first names: %.*s\n", (int)(p - full_name), full_name );

    printf( "last name: %s\n", p + 1 );
}

int main( void )
{
    //Note that we can now pass a read-only string
    //string, because we are not using strtok anymore.
    print_names( "jack joe jes woo" );
}
```

This program has exactly the same output as the other program.